# Limitar tiempo de funcion php

Tags: php, date, url, function

Estoy cargando links de "ipAPIs de geolocalización".
Si demora en cargar uno, pruebo otro y así con todos. ¿Cómo se hace eso? por ejemplo darle dos segundo para que cargue, si no carga, lo termino y prueba el siguiente.

Puse dos funciones que los abren

(así lo piden los sitios para entrar):

```
<?php
/*--------------link_1------------*/

$userIP = $_SERVER [ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ];  
$apiURL = 'http://ip-api.com/json/'.$userIP;  
$ch = curl_init($apiURL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$apiResponse = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
$ipData = json_decode($apiResponse, true);
echo "<pre>",print_r($ipData),"</pre>";

/*--------------link_2------------*/

echo $var_export ( unserialize ( file_get_contents ( 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER [ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ] ) ) ) ;
?>
```

Probé dándoles un temporizador de 2 segundos a las funciones y encontre
la función:
set_time_limit() pero cierra todo el script al terminar los dos seg.

¿Se puede hacer un temporizador de funciones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero; dale un vistazo a la documentacion: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - Especifica el numero de segundos a esperar mientras intenta la conexcion, usar 0 para esperar indefinidamente.

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - Especifica el numero maximo de segundos que puede esperar curl para ejecutarse.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2); //en segundos
```

Recuerda tambien alargar el tiempo de ejecucion de tu script de manera equivalente:

```
set_time_limit(0);// por ejemplo, ejecutar idefinidamente
```

Comment: Lo hice y funcionó
Tienes razón
Un simple código de funciones no haría demasiado
Curl tiene muchas propiedades para los links